# find a CTransaction from a prevout in Bitcoin source code

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, c++

I'm trying to come up with this function: `CTransaction getTxFromPrevout(COutPoint prevo);`

The idea being... when a new transaction is about to be validated, it will go through all of it's `tx.vin[i].prevout` and check for them funds (`utxo`).

So I want to find and identify the `CTransaction tx` such that `tx.vout` (of type `vector<CTxOut>` ) has any `i` element such that it's `CScript` is a normal payment (`tx.vout[i].scriptPubKey.IsNormalPayment() == true`) and the `tx.vout[i].scriptPubKey` has within it a match for the `prevo`

If I use a web based explorer I can take the `prevo` and extract the hash from it, then search the web for the `tx`... but that doesn't help me, since I want to be able to use this within the code itself, adding this new function. I tried following the code on an explorer and it uses the rpc api, and it was not easy to follow.

What I'm thinking is that there should be a `utxo` database structure or class that will make this easier to crawl through. If I suppose there is such a class named `UTxODatabase` - that I know there isn't, but just imagine there is - then the function I need to code would look like this:

`CTransaction UTxODatabase::getTxFromPrevout(COutPoint prevo);`

/*************************************************/

**EDIT 1:**
I put this at the very end of the CheckTransaction() function, in `main.cpp`

`BOOST_FOREACH (const CTxIn& txin, tx.vin){
        std::cout << "txin.prevPubKey.ToString(): " << txin.prevPubKey.ToString() << std::endl;`

Then I've ran the wallet and the output shown for each txin was just: `txin.prevPubKey.ToString:`, without any `prevPubKey` data.
I am really confused about this.

My thinking was that if I'm able to get those `prevPubKey`s from the `CTxIn`, then I'll be able to track the `utxo`. But why would there be no information on that member of the `txin` at that stage?

Comment: There is a utxo database See `CCoinsView` class in `coins.h`, the function `virtual bool GetCoin(const COutPoint &outpoint, Coin &coin) const;` (or one of its overloads) might do what you need.

Comment: I'm confused about that `virtual` qualifier... the main function you referenced me to was:
 `bool CCoinsView::GetCoins(const uint256& txid, CCoins& coins) const { return false; }
` ... it just returns false.

This seems to be on the right track, tho... and probably one of the other implementations should work...  like this one:
`bool CCoinsViewBacked::GetCoins(const uint256& txid, CCoins& coins) const { return base->GetCoins(txid, coins); }`

But the truth is I'm not sure on how to use it
Could be something like this?
`CTransaction CCoinsViewBacked::getTxFromPrevout(COutPoint prevo);`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use this function:

`bool CCoinsViewMemPool::GetCoin(const COutPoint &outpoint, Coin &coin) const`

You can find the definition here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.17.0.1/src/txmempool.cpp#L885

It will set the `Coin` object you pass as an argument. For an example of usage, see `bool CheckSequenceLocks(const CTransaction &tx, int flags, LockPoints* lp, bool useExistingLockPoints)` in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.17.0.1/src/validation.cpp#L364

This is supposed to "provide access to all Coins which are either unspent in the
 `* base CCoinsView`, or are outputs from any mempool transaction".

Comment: OP is asking for the transaction, not just the UTXO. That's just not possible unless you have `txindex=1` and no pruning.

Comment: I misunderstood, then.

Comment: Actually, OP may be confused and not need the full transaction for his purpose.

Comment: Agreed! I might not need the whole transaction... but at least I want to be able to validate/compare/check the address to where each of the `utxo` is pointing at.